# onBoundary event doesn't fire in Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 and above

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, text-to-speech, ubuntu-22.04, webspeech-api

Better a good example than a long talk, right?

```js
utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance()
utter.onboundary = console.log
utter.lang = 'en-US'
utter.text = 'This is a sentence'
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utter)
```

On Chrome build Version 109.0.5414.74 (Build officiel) (64 bits), on Ubuntu 22.04, the boundary event is never fired.

**Warning**: For some reason, the above snippet doesn't run at all for me on Chrome, but it works if I copy it to the console in the dev tools. The boundary event is still not triggered, though.

Is it working for you?

**Edit**: After investigating on different browser and OS, this seems like a bug that happens only on Chrome/Chromium, and only under Linux.

Comment: I ran your code snippet in firefox and it works

Comment: Correct: https://imgur.com/3aTyKYX

Comment: It doesn't do anything in Chrome 109. Definitely a bug. Works in console.

Comment: Just to clarify, it works in console, do you mean that you see a log for the boundary event? Because I get the speech too in console, but not the boundary event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251274/discussion-between-slava-knyazev-and-sharcoux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`boundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/boundary_event) event does not fire in Chrome on Ubuntu because all of the provided `SpeechSynthesisVoice`'s on the platform are network based. You can see this be running a quick filter on the returned array:

```js
speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(({ localService }) => localService)
```

Which will return an empty array `[]` because all voices are supplied by a remote speech synthesizer.

This is a known issue and the associated bug has been marked as **WontFix**. I quote the remarks from [comment 7](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521666#c7) (emphasis mine):

> The boundary event is not supported for all speech engines.
>
> Native speech synthesis on Mac OS X, Windows, and Chrome OS all support boundary events at the word level.
>
> **Network-based speech synthesis**, and Android speech synthesis don't currently support these. There's no immediate plans to fix those as the *upstream APIs literally don't expose them at all*.

Unfortunately there is not much you can do as the platforms simply don't support boundary events at the word level.